# How to show message when doing ajax submit in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am trying out Primefaces 3 using glassfish and eclipse.

I wanted to utilize Primefaces Dialog when creating or entering user details.
Suppose for example in a page, I have a Create button that when clicked would show this dialog.

```
<p:dialog id="dialog"  widgetVar="dlg1">
    <h:form id="addMemberForm">
            <!-- More code here -->
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Save"
                    actionListener="#{myBean.save}"
                    oncomplete="dlg1.hide()"  />
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

..and when my save button is clicked, execute this code.

```
public class MyBean{
    public void save(ActionEvent event) {
        try{
            myEJB.addMember(newMember);
            //how to show message
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I show a dialog popup message to the user when the add is successful.

I tried it with this code but this doesn't show up and the dialog gets dismissed.

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Successful add!");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

I was thinking that this is an ajax submit so everything gets cleared.

I think I have to execute some code during the oncomplete but I dont know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should update a message tag from your ajax request.

Assuming you have a global message tag like this on your page:

```html
<h:messages id="msg"/>
```

Since it is not inside the dialog's form you need to address it in the `update` attribute of `p:commandButton` with an absolute id:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Save"
                 actionListener="#{myBean.save}"
                 oncomplete="dlg1.hide()"
                 update=":msg"  />
```